# The meaning of the words, "board demand"?

Tags: meaning

Could you help me about the meaning of the words, "board demand"?

I am now reading a document about power generating company of foreign country. In the document, I couldn't understand a sentence, "The electricity board demand of the district is March. "

I think the "highest demand", or the "demand used for the prediction of the next year", but I couldn't find out the correct answer.

Comment: It's the _electricity board_ which is (/who are) making the demand. But they need to improve their writing skills.

Comment: That's because it doesn't make any sense.  (Though perhaps it might, with a bit of context.)

Comment: @HotLicks It does make sense. In BrE singular agreement is used for certain bodies where AmE would use plural agreement. Here the electricity board have made a demand (that the district provide something or cause something to occur in March).

Comment: @Dan Bron You think that 'Their demand of the district ...' is idiomatic? I disagree. The only examples of 'His demand of X' where X is not the thing demanded that I've found in a quick Google search have X as the thing demanded. Apart from the odd pre-20th-century example.

Comment: @DanBron - Like I said, it might make sense with some decent context.  (But I have to believe that it's poor English on either side of the pond.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Seems fine to me. “The district said it would make a decision in April. The electricity board did not accept that. The electricity board [‘s] demand of the district is [the decision be made in] March”.

Comment: No Google hits for "his/their demand of the district/people".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No google hits for “*blue* ideas sleep furiously” either but that doesn’t mean it’s ungrammatical. In general you can’t rely on google to determine grammaticality, and the chances of finding someone who has *also* said precisely X decreases exponentially with the number of words in X.

Comment: @DanBron You're not comparing like with like. 'Blue ideas sleep furiously' has problems other than a grammatical one. But in any case, neither of these is _idiomatic_. The term I used, and you seem to have disregarded.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The phrase [*colorless green ideas sleep furiously*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously) is a famous example of a perfectly grammatical sentence which no one would ever utter. I changed “green” to “blue” to because googling the one would find lots of hits and the other zero hits, to demonstrate the folly of using google for such tests. For me, as a descriptivist, the border between *grammatical* and *idiomatic* is very blurry indeed. In any case, my position remains the same: the sentence is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am really sorry that this sentence isn't written in right English and the whole context wasn't in mysterious post. The context is like, "the electricity board demand in the XYZ district is March, but it is almost the same demand from December to March so there is no problem to use the values from the survey in December."

Comment: @Kojisugi Ah. In that case, you can drop the word “board” altogether. It just means “electricity demand”.

Comment: Are they talking about electricity demand ? The area will 'demand' a certain amount of electricity during March, that is to say the electrical appliances in the area will draw a certain amount of current from the power supply during that month.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I understand that "board " may not have much meaning in this case.

Comment: As I said, without more context it's gibberish.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It should read as 
“The electricity-board's demand of the district is March.” Definitely the hyphen (`-`), probably the possessive s (`'s`).

As to the demand being a month in spring, is anyone's guess.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand well about the meaning.